# Does XCODE have any autocorrect functionality

Tags: xcode

Does XCODE have some sort of autocorrect?

I keep typing **CGFLoat** instead of **CGFloat** and would love to know if there is a way to make this autocorrect down to CGFloat

Thanks!

Comment: When you type `CG`, Xcode will show some vars or methods matched with.
You can use 'TAB' or just select and 'RETURN'.

Comment: OS X itself has such as feature. It's somewhere in system preferences and then keyboard maybe? I can't tell from the top of my head but you should be able to replace it globally there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Settings > Keyboard > Text.
2. Click the + sign on the bottom left to add a new text replacement.
3. In the Replace column, put the word you want OS X to stop autocorrecting (no spaces are allowed).
4. In the With column, put the exact same word you put in the Replace column.